# Are emoji color preferences stored somewhere on MacOS?

Tags: macos, file, color, emoji

So I want to programmatically detect which color I used last for an emoji, e. g. if I used the  emoji with the darkest skin tone () last, is there a place where that information is stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ascertaining the last color used of a changeable emojis.**

Testing under **macOS Catalina**, when one makes changes within **Emoji & Symbols**, at least some of these changes are written to:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.EmojiPreferences.plist
```

In **Terminal**, run:

```
defaults read com.apple.EmojiPreferences
```

Then look at the output under `EMFSkinToneBaseKeyPreferences`, and for the emojis you've shown, it will most likely look like e.g.:

```
"\\Ud83d\\Udc4c" = "\\Ud83d\\Udc4c\\Ud83c\\Udfff";
```

While the `defaults` *command* is the normal one used with **.plist** *files*, nonetheless there is also `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`, and it may be easier in some cases than `defaults` when trying to retries nested *keys*.

In this particular use case if gives a visual representation of the emojis color change:

In **Terminal**:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \
"Print :EMFDefaultsKey:EMFSkinToneBaseKeyPreferences" \
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.EmojiPreferences.plist 
Dict {
     = 
}
```

The default color of the emojis shows on the left of the *equal sign* and the last used color shows on the right.

Only changeable emoji that have been previously set from the default color will show, as well as any reset on a given changeable emojis.

As I know you use **AppleScript**, here is a programmatic solution to retrieving and displaying then information from the `EMFSkinToneBaseKeyPreferences` *key*:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c ", ¬
    "'Print :EMFDefaultsKey:EMFSkinToneBaseKeyPreferences' ", ¬
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.EmojiPreferences.plist ", ¬
    "| awk '/=/{sub(/^    /, \"\t\t\t\t\t\", $0); print}'"} ¬
    as string

set lastUsedColors to (do shell script shellCMD)

display dialog ¬
    "Last used color for changable Emoji:" & ¬
    linefeed & linefeed & lastUsedColors ¬
    buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
    with title "Emoji & Symbols"
```

**Displays the following example dialog:**

[image]

---

**Ascertaining the last used *character/emojis/symbol*.**

On a side note, if one is interested in knowing which was the last used *character/emojis/symbol*...

There are two *keys* to look at in the output of the `defaults` *command*:

- `EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey`
- `EMFUsageHistoryKey`

After the use of additional *character/emojis* and looking at the *value* of the `EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey` *key* in relation to which was the actual *character/emojis/symbol* last used, the *value* of the last used *character/emojis* will be a `-1` of its *value* and will appear in the *array* for the *character/emojis/symbol* last used under the `EMFUsageHistoryKey` *key*.

As an example, right now the *value* of the `EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey` *key* is `53` and I'm going to *double-click* the  emojis from **Frequently Used** in the **Character Viewer** while in **TextEdit** and watch for the update to the  *array* under the `EMFUsageHistoryKey` *key*.

The the `EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey` *key* went from `53` to `55` while `54` was added to the  *array* under the`EMFUsageHistoryKey` *key*.

Now it a matter of parsing the `EMFUsageHistoryKey` *key* to ascertain the *value* of the *array* that has the `(value of EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey key) - 1` *value* to determine which was the actual last *character/emojis/symbol* used.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will ascertain the last used character/emojis symbol from **Emoji & Symbols** and display as dialog with its results:

```applescript
set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c ", ¬
    "'Print :EMFDefaultsKey:EMFRecentSequenceNumberKey' ", ¬
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.EmojiPreferences.plist"} ¬
    as string

set searchNumber to (do shell script shellCMD) - 1 as string

set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c ", ¬
    "'Print :EMFDefaultsKey:EMFUsageHistoryKey:' ", ¬
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.EmojiPreferences.plist ", ¬
    "| awk '/Array|", searchNumber, "/{print $1}'"} ¬
    as string

set awkOutput to paragraphs of (do shell script shellCMD)

repeat with i from 1 to count awkOutput
    if item i of awkOutput is equal to searchNumber then
        set lastUsedCharacterEmojisSymbol to ¬
            item (i - 1) of awkOutput
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

display dialog ¬
    "The last used character/emojis/symbol was: " & ¬
    lastUsedCharacterEmojisSymbol buttons {"OK"} ¬
    default button 1 with title "Emoji & Symbols"
```

---

**Displays the following example dialog:**

[image]